# Enter Parameter Value Dialog Box

Tags: ms-access

I copied a report from another database, and changed a control source for a textbox to match a column in my current recordsource (which is a query). But I still keep getting the 
"Enter Parameter Dialog" box with the name of the column I changed. I tried running just the query and it works fine, I don't get the Dialog box then. But when I try running the report,
I keep getting the dialog box. 
(ORDERDT is the name of the column in the query in OLD database, which I changed it to match to the column , ORDERDATE in the new query in the new DB)

So I ran the database documenter and got the following result:

```
Objects

Group Level 0
ControlSource: SITE GroupFooter: True
GroupHeader: True GroupInterval: 1
GroupOn: Each Value KeepTogether: Per Page
SortOrder: False

Group Level 1
ControlSource: Customer GroupFooter: False
GroupHeader: False GroupInterval: 1
GroupOn: Each Value KeepTogether: Per Page
SortOrder: False

Group Level 2
ControlSource: ORDERDT GroupFooter: False
GroupHeader: False GroupInterval: 1
GroupOn: Each Value KeepTogether: Per Page
SortOrder: False
```

So does the result mean, the old 'ORDERDT' column or text still exists somewhere on the report?

I was not able to find it anywhere on my report.

Can somebody decode what the result of the database documenter means?

Comment: I got it...The report is grouped by the old 'ORDERDT', so changed it to the new 'ORDERDATE' by right clicking the detail section of the report->Sorting and Grouping

Comment: Make sure to Post your own Answer if the question has been solved with your resolution, even though it may be simply boneheaded mistake :)

Comment: I guess thats what I did above!